# how to add CSS class inside DataTables Javascript

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am trying to add the CSS class `check` for the id and code. The CSS is not working. Is there any possible ways to add a CSS class here? I tried this within the quotation marks as well.

```js
DataTable('Entity', [{
    "data": "Id",
    "name": "Id",
    "autoWidth": true,
    className: check
  },
  {
    "data": "Code",
    "name": "Code",
    "autoWidth": true,
    className: check
  },
],);
```

Comment: Can you try using quotes: className: "check"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below setting while rendering DataTable

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 3,
    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
      if ( cellData < 1 ) {
        $(td).css('color', 'red');
        $(td).addClass("yourclass");
      }
    }
  }]
});
```